# Си.Маленькая программка.Структуры.Поиск информации в структуре

Tags: c, структуры, текст, структуры-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот , собственно, сама задачка.
А вот и сам код.Только не могу понять, в чем ошибка.Почему не верно сравнивается в цикле..Первый элемент с нужным названием ищется верно(элемент с которым я потом буду сравнивать все последующие с таким же названием.)Я был бы очень рад, если бы вы нашли мою ошибку..(Извиняюсь заранее за глупые ошибки , я не умышленно )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int j , i;
        FILE *f;
        char name [25];
        printf ("enter the name of the file: ");
        scanf ("%s", name);
        if((f = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf ("file not found");
            system ("PAUSE");

        }

        typedef struct{
            char Name[30];
            char Price[30];
            char Shelf_life[30];
        
        }stuff;
        int n=0,k;
        stuff a;
        stuff *x=NULL;
        while (!feof(f)){
            if(fscanf (f,"%s", a.Name)!=1)
                       break;
            fscanf (f,"%s",a.Price);
            fscanf (f,"%s",a.Shelf_life);
            x=(stuff*)realloc(x,sizeof(stuff)*(n+1));
            x[n]=a;
            n++;             
        }
        
        fclose(f);
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("%s %s %s\n", x[i].Name,x[i].Price,x[i].Shelf_life);}  
        
         char Name[30];
         printf("enter the product name :  \n");
         scanf (" %s", Name);
        int t,s,min=0;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            if (strcmp(x[i].Name, Name) == 0){
                t=i;
            break;  
            }
            
        }
        
        for (s=t+1;s<n;s++ ){
            if (strcmp(x[s].Name, Name) == 0){
                if (strcmp(x[s].Price,x[t].Price) < 0){
                    min=s;
                }
                else {
                min=t;}
            }   
        }
        printf("minimum price : %s \n", x[min].Price);
        system("PAUSE"); 
        free(x); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

А вот что выводит сама программа...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Небольшой вопрос. А зачем Price хранить в виде массива чаров? Почему не int&

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов компилятор начинает немного ругаться и выдает подобные строки  - passing argument from incompatible pointer type
Хотя программа всё равно запускается.
Но, к сожалению, это не решает мою проблему cо сравнениями.. ... :'/

Comment: Не решает. А чтобы компилятор не ругался (там наверное parsing?) имеет смысл  посмотреть ключи форматов fscanf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое совпадение наименования у Вас дает Вам `Price`=28. И сравниваете Вы дальше только с ним. Сделайте следующее:

1. Строку `min = t` переставьте перед циклом поиска минимума, в ветке
   `else` она не нужна.
2. Измените сравнение `Priсe` на такое:
   `(strcmp(x[s].Price, x[min].Price) < 0)`.

Comment: Премного благодарен за помощь ! Спасибо :)